# How to display progress during a NSIS Installation, when installer calls the uninstaller in silent mode?

Tags: nsis

I have an **NSIS installer** which uninstalls the older version through this command

`ExecWait "$INSTDIR\temp\uninstall.exe /S _?=$INSTDIR"`

The installer is supposed to wait till uninstall of the old version is complete and then proceed with the new installation. The problem is, the user does not see any progress in the installation window for a long time (the uninstaller has to delete some huge directories, so it takes its own sweet time).

We do not want to remove the `/S` switch as it will pop up the uninstaller window and the user has to do a couple of clicks to proceed with uninstall and finally close the uninstaller.

Is there anyway by which i can show some progress in the installer window while executing the uninstaller in silent mode?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get feedback when /S is used. What you could do is to make up your own parameter and tweak the uninstaller:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh

UninstPage uninstConfirm un.skipifsilentprogress
UninstPage instFiles

Function un.skipifsilentprogress
ClearErrors
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} "$0" "/UIS" $1
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    SetAutoClose true ;Make sure user does not have to click close
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section uninstall
Detailprint uninstalling...
Sleep 555
Sleep 555
Sleep 555
SectionEnd
```

And run it with the special /UIS switch...

Comment: Thanks! Will try using the custom switch.